# AVPlayer autostart in SceneKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avplayer, scenekit, avkit

I have an AVPlayer used in SpriteKit as a material of SceneKit node. However, the AVPlayer will always auto start! I have tried to put the code in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear (as some answers), but it still load automatically.

My code is something like this:

```
var apple1984Video:AVPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    apple1984Video = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "apple1984", withExtension:"mp4")!)
    apple1984Video.actionAtItemEnd =.none
    apple1984Video.pause()

    let ad1 = addVideo(apple1984Video, name:"apple1984", position:SCNVector3(-0.1, -0.1, -0.5))
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ad1)
    ...
}
```

What can I do to stop the autoplay?

PS: here's the addVideo function but it is primary related to SceneKit/SpriteKit stuffs. I did not called play() in other parts of program.

```
func addVideo(_ player:AVPlayer, name:String, position:SCNVector3) -> SCNNode {
    let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: sceneView.frame.width, height: sceneView.frame.height))
    spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    spriteKitScene.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)

    // Create the SpriteKit video node, containing the video player

    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
    videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width / 2.0, y: spriteKitScene.size.height / 2.0)
    videoNode.size = spriteKitScene.size
    videoNode.yScale = -1.0
    videoNode.alpha = 0.9
    spriteKitScene.addChild(videoNode)

    let geometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.4, height: 0.3)
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)

    geometry.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene

    node.name = name
    node.position = position
    player.pause()
    return node
}
```

Comment: hmmm possibly show u the addVideo func? And there is no videoPlayer.play() later on?

Comment: Done, thought they are not quite related as they are primary SceneKit/SpriteKit stuffs. I have also tried returning SKVideoNode instead of AVPlayer but it also autoplayed.

Comment: if you pause the video inside the func before add it to the scene?

Comment: Check if the video player attached to the video node is the same as the vidso player you create.  It could be making a copy, and you are pausing the wrong instance

Comment: Thanks to @Knight0fDragon suggestion, I create the AVPlayer outside the function and pass in the player, make sure it is the only copy. And I placed pause() to the player before calling and inside the function. But the video still auto-play.

Comment: no no, you got it backwards,  you need to verify the video player inside the SKVideoNode

Comment: Note: If you are targeting iOS11 you can try setting the AVPlayer directly to the material property.

Comment: do `videoNode.pause()` inside your function

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I just updated my code.

Comment: @Toyos this works, and might solved the issue... let me test, thanks!

Comment: pause the `videoNode`, not the avPlayer

Comment: I would be inclined to try this out in SpriteKit first, just to reduce the number of debugging variables. I recently made a small project with avPlayer and SKVideoNode that is working properly, if you want to look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44989379/6593818

Comment: @Toyos solved the issue but removing the SpriteKit layer directly! Applying AVPlayer to material works.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks. I tried this in my previous version (didn't try it after the changes) and it does not work. But the issue is now solved with SpriteKit layer directly removed.